How to manually calculate survival probabilities using flexsurvspline models
I fit a parametric survival model using flexsurvspline from flexsurv package, and would like to mannually calculate predicted survival probabilities with new data at given time points. The R code example is presented as follows. I know we can predict survivals using the summary function, but mannual calculation using extracted coefficients gives more flexibility in future use, e.g. as an imbeded function in a Markov model.
library(flexsurv)
library(splines)

n <- 100
time <- rexp(n, rate = 0.1)
status <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)
cov1 <- rnorm(n)
cov2 <- rnorm(n)
dt <- data.frame(time = time, status = status, cov1 = cov1, cov2 = cov2)

fit <- flexsurvspline(Surv(time, status) ~ cov1 * cov2 + gamma1(cov1) + gamma1(cov2), data = dt, k = 1, scale = "normal")

Does anyone know how to calculate survival using the following coefficients extracted from the model? For example:
Extract model coefficients
coefs <- fit$res[, "est"]
New data
new_dt <- data.frame(cov = 1, cov2 = 2)
time points
time_points <- 1:10
Many thanks!
I have tried asking AI, without satisfactory answers. I have contacted the package author, who suggested me to using the summary function, but I am keen to know how to calculate survival using extracted coefficients.

Voting to close as needing details or clarity. As posed it asked for some parameters about a single dataset fit, bt when offered a potential solution the questioner says it was really in service of a multiply imputed list object for which there is no example in the question.
